# Disable winston's verbose startup logs

Tags: winston

When my app starts winston logs all kinds of stuff, e.g.

```
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "error"
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "warn"
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "info"
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "http"
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "verbose"
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "debug"
winston:create-logger Define prototype method for "silly"
winston:file written true false
winston:file stat done: combined.log
...lots more
```

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

Set the following property in your environment variables:

```
DEBUG=-winston:create-logger
```

Also see: https://github.com/3rd-Eden/diagnostics/issues/20